# how can I change height value to cell or column of datagridveiw , by c# code?

Tags: c#

how can I change height value to cell or column of datagridveiw , by c# code?

Answer (score 0):

You can change height of row with [DataGridViewRow.Height](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.height.aspx). If you mean only one cell then I can't imagine how it will looks.

*added:*
Hope this helps:

```
   dataGridView1.RowTemplate.Height = 50;
   foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dataGridView1.Rows)
       r.Height = 50;
```

Comment: I use with DataGridVeiw, not with DataGridVeiwRow

Comment: DataGridView.Rows property has collection of DataGridViewRows

Comment: it not response, by the debuger I see that r.height stay in the previous value